# Amazon Corretto Garbage Collection parameters

Tags: java, garbage-collection, corretto

I have recently migrated one of my project to use Amazon Corretto 11 instead of OpenJDK.I would like to understand Garbage Collection parameters of Amazon Corretto 11. Can someone please share my right pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Corretto is based on OpenJDK. From it's [website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-17-ug/what-is-corretto-17.html):

> Amazon Corretto 17 is a no-cost, multiplatform, production-ready distribution of the Open Java Development Kit (OpenJDK). Corretto 17 comes with long-term support that includes performance enhancements and security fixes.

So all your OpenJDK Garbage Collection settings should apply for Amazon Corretto as well. To list all available options for your current version:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version
```

Head over to Oracle's [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html#advanced-garbage-collection-options-for-java) for all Garbage Collection related flags if you need some docs.